# EOFException with GZIP Compression

Tags: http-post, jax-rs, resteasy, fgsl

I enabled the GZIP compression for the REST API and during testing, I am getting an EOFException exception.

The Endpoint annotations are here:-

```
@POST
@Path("/")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
@GZIP
```

Even though I removed the @ZIP annotation still I am getting the same error.

The test case code is here:-

```
 val compressedPayLoad = EntityBuilder.create()
        .setText(jsonLoader.loadAsString("abc.json"))
        .gzipCompress()
        .build()
    val req = HttpPost("$rootPath/").entity(compressedPayLoad).addAuthorization()
   
    req.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_ENCODING, "gzip")
    req.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString())

    val resp = execute(req)
    assertEquals(200, resp.statusLine.statusCode)
```

I added the Provider classes in the METE-INF.services folder

```
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.GZIPDecodingInterceptor
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.GZIPEncodingInterceptor
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.AcceptEncodingGZIPFilter
```

During debugging I found the Interparator method called twice and My assumption is that stream is being consumed twice on the server-side, making it “empty” for the second consumer.

Note:- .addAuthorization() is our internal helper function.

The logs from the service are here:-

```
Interceptor Context: org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.ServerReaderInterceptorContext,  Method : proceed
DEBUG o.j.r.r.i18n ReaderInterceptor: org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.GZIPDecodingInterceptor
DEBUG o.j.r.r.i18n Interceptor : org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.GZIPDecodingInterceptor,  Method : aroundReadFrom
DEBUG o.j.r.r.i18n Interceptor Context: org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.ServerReaderInterceptorContext,  Method : proceed
DEBUG o.j.r.r.i18n MessageBodyReader: org.jboss.resteasy.core.providerfactory.SortedKey
DEBUG o.j.r.r.i18n MessageBodyReader: org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jackson.ResteasyJackson2Provider
DEBUG o.j.r.r.i18n Provider : org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jackson.ResteasyJackson2Provider,  Method : readFrom
DEBUG o.j.r.r.i18n Interceptor : org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.GZIPDecodingInterceptor$FinishableGZIPInputStream,  Method : read
DEBUG o.j.r.r.i18n Interceptor Context: org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.ServerReaderInterceptorContext,  Method : proceed
DEBUG o.j.r.r.i18n ReaderInterceptor: org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.GZIPDecodingInterceptor
DEBUG o.j.r.r.i18n Interceptor : org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.GZIPDecodingInterceptor,  Method : aroundReadFrom
ERROR c.t.s.e.CatchAllExceptionMapper Unhandled exception
java.io.EOFException: null
```

Here we can see the **aroundReadFrom** method called twice. Is there anything that I am missing or anyone faced this issue before. Please help me with this.

Comment: My assumption is it's likely called twice for authentication purposes. What version of RESTEasy are you using?